# Can the center color be repositioned in an android radial-gradient drawable?

Tags: android, drawable, gradient, android-xml

It is easy to achieve the below gradient at left using standard start, center, and end colors in a radial gradient with android in which the start = yellow, center = purple, and end = blue. The circle at right however requires the repositioning of the center color. Is this possible?

[image]

The result at left can be reproduced with something like:

```
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <gradient
            android:endColor="#0000ff"
            android:gradientRadius="my_radius"
            android:centerColor="#770077"
            android:startColor="#00ffff"
            android:type="radial"/>
    </shape>
```

I am wondering if I can shift the center color to achieve the gradient at right. I believe the answer is no, but I would like to see if anyone has discovered a way in which to do this. Thanks!

Comment: No. I am fairly certain this is not possible, but am leaving it unanswered until someone has done better research into the problem than I.

Comment: just stumbled over your post, need similar. Afaik this is not possible just in xml i think. If you use the ShaderFactory even this sounds immpossible to me as center is always 0.5.

Comment: centerX and centerY property of gradient seem to have no baring. I believe that is what should determine the center, but it doesn't change anything.  I consider this a bug in android

Answer (score 3):

Sadly, this cannot be achieved via XML declarations, however, it is possible to do via code.

Here's a quick code sample:

```
public class MyDrawing extends View 
{   
    private Paint mPaint;

    public MyDrawing(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public MyDrawing(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public MyDrawing(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init()
    {
        int [] colors = new int[] { 0xff0000ff, 0xff00ff00, 0xffff0000 };
        float [] positions = new float[] { 0.4f, 0.7f, 0.9f };

        RadialGradient gradient = new RadialGradient(50, 50, 50, colors, positions, TileMode.CLAMP);                
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setShader(gradient);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
    {           
        super.onDraw(canvas);                               

        canvas.drawCircle(circleX, circleY, circleRadius, mPaint);      
    }
}
```

Two things you should pay attention to:

1. In the colors array, you must specify the alpha (the 1st to chars). In my example, I specified both as "ff", meaning no transparency. If you don't specify the alpha, it will default to 0.
2. The positions array specifies the positioning or strength of each color in the gradient. Play around with this to achieve the result you're looking for.

Hope this helps :)